# Python Selenium - how to click full screen button of a video without a frame

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working with selenium for the first time, and I'm trying to play a video on another website.
I've already managed to play the video, but now I'm stuck trying to make it full-screen. The full-screen button is hidden unless I hover with my mouse over it.

So I searched for a solution and everybody suggests to use `switch_to.frame()` and then access the button, but it seems like no frame surrounds the video in my case. I'm not an expert in HTML so maybe I am getting this wrong, but is there a way to click that full-screen button when there's no frame surrounding the video?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: JavaScript click?

Comment: Yes, I guess, are there other types of clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there isn't an iframe containing the video, you should be able to click the button like you would any other on the screen. To get the hover menu to appear you can use `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()`.

If you're having issues finding the button, you may also be able to `video_player.send_keys("f")`. Many players will use that shortcut to switch to fullscreen.